# Why is @PostConstruct recognised in my case?

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

Could you tell me why does a method annotated with `@PostContruct` runs in my case? As far as I know, a method with `@PostContruct` is processed by Bean Post Processors. If you want to activate the default `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` you need to add `<context:annotation-config/>` in the XML configuration but I want to use only annotation config. In my case, `@ComponentScan` in configuration is pointed to the `service`. It means that only classes from this package candidates to be instantiated.

Configuration class:

```
package config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "service")
public class AppConfig {
}
```

Simple class:

```
package service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Component
public class Simple {

    @PostConstruct
    private void sout(){
        System.out.println("SOUT");
    }
}
```

And the launcher:

```
import config.AppConfig;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import service.Simple;

public class Launcher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        Simple simple = ctx.getBean("simple", Simple.class);
    }

}
```

The output of the app is "SOUT". Could you explain be who invokes the `@PostContruct` method and how?

Comment: Because you use the `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` it is automatically assumed you want to process all annotations. What you are stating is true for XML driven configuration as that doesn't have annotation processing enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

`AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` is an alternative to XML based configurations. When you use it to create objects, it first creates the object and the `@Autowired` properties,  and then calls the `@PostConstruct` method. It is a handy alternative to writing a `setup()` or `init()` method  which you would have to call yourself.